# space leaves in website after the last div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

http://www.cjofficial.in

Please Check the Website Via Inspect Element After Clicking a Tab(animation),
There Is Some Space Left Freeley After The last Div..
its showing after the animation of div which is moving from bottom of page to upside..
Please Help Me To Remove That..
Javascript File example.js is Linked to the Site Please Check That Too

Comment: It is because you have given height:100% to #content_hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding the following code to your CSS:

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:99%; }    this worked out

Answer (score 0):

Don't give height:100% to #content_hold .

Answer (score 0):

That extra space is because #content has height:100%;
Looking at your design I recommend you to wrap your page in a div and give following css to it :

```
.page-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

The layout you are trying to achieve can be built easily with flexbox. The [support of flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is good.